# Passing variables from server-side javascript to client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

OK. I spent all day on this problem with no solution. I've got a client-side html page that I am wanting to embed another server-side html page into that would contain a jQuery autocomplete input textbox. The reason I want to do this is so the ajax in the autocomplete can directly access a php file also sitting on the server and not use jsonP requests. To do this is not a problem.

Problem: Once the user has selected a value from the autocomplete, I need to send that value (out of the server-side js in embedded browser) back to the client-side js (in the main browser js) for further processing. I'm using an embedded OLE Microsoft web browser inside the main browser app. (I know this is not ideal, but we're using a third party plugin that uses ActiveX). I thought of maybe changing a property of the embedded browser control such as status text, assigning it the value and recognizing that event in the main browser, but the browser control doesn't allow changing of properties (besides width and height) via js.

I'm completely open to ideas that take a different route if there are no solutions to this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can send data to another client-side page from one, it has to go through some sort of server-side page with PHP or another server language.

BTW there's no such thing as server-side JS, but I understand why it seems like it in this situation.

Comment: >> there's no such thing as server-side JS << I know what you mean in this context, but don't forget Node.js, Rhino, etc. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript

Comment: @Adam: Your proposed edit of an old question is the wrong way. Please ask a new question that links to this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your requirements clearly, but does [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) help?